# Login error in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Login error in asp.net like the name `UserName` does not exist in the current context and The name `Password` does not exist in the current context.
Asp.code

```
 <asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" BackColor="#F7F7DE" BorderColor="#CCCC99" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="10pt" Height="242px" Width="448px">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table cellpadding="0" style="height:242px;width:448px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2" style="color:White;background-color:#6B696B;font-weight:bold;">Log In</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">Username:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" ErrorMessage="User Name is required." ToolTip="User Name is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password" ErrorMessage="Password is required." ToolTip="Password is required." ValidationGroup="Login1">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="RememberMe" runat="server" Text="Remember me next time." />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" ValidationGroup="Login1" OnClick="LoginButton_Click" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" />
</asp:Login>
```

C# code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Project_DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString)

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from signin where Username =@username and Password=@password", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UserName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Password.Text);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Username and Password')</script>");
    }
```

Comment: what are UserName and Password and where are they defined?

Comment: Please do not write the whole question in **Subject**

Comment: `Doesn't exists in the current context` is the compile time error. It occurs when you an object or a variable which is out of scope.

Comment: I strongly suspect you are storing your passwords as a plain text. **Never store passwords in plain text!** Use [SHA-512 hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2).

Answer (score 1):

On the login control you need to use the FindControl to get this two TextBox and they are not direct available to the page.

So use this to get access to them

```
TextBox TheUserName = Login1.FindControl("UserName") as TextBox;
TextBox ThePassword = Login1.FindControl("Password") as TextBox;
```

and then use them on your code

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TheUserName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", ThePassword.Text);
```

Comment: @user3797140 So please check the answer as correct, and vote.